# Identify HTML elements when event triggers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have my app with tons of buttons/inputs/etc. with different events. I want to clearly identify each one of them which some event triggers on.

For example, when I have a piece of my app:

```
<div class="someClass">
  <div>
    <someOtherElement>
      <div></div>
      <div><button ng-click="someClickEvent($event)"></button></div>
    </someOtherElement>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to identify somehow, which button I have just clicked:

```
function someClickEvent(e) {
   // some identification code here
}
```

**[edit]**

Maybe I wrote this wrong... I want some identification like `XPath` or something that will point which button were triggered (for error logging purposes).

So when I click my `button` and some error occurs, I want to identify the button and log some information about it (e.g. `div[0].someClass>div[0]>someOtherElement[0]>div[1]>button[0]`).

Comment: Do you want to identify the button with the id attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get identify the button and log it by this:

```
$scope.clickFunc = function(event){
   $scope.clickedElement = event.target.outerHTML;
};
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rjdzuxaL/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-click` instead on `onclick`

```
<button  ng-click="myFunction($event)">test</button>
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rjdzuxaL/)

Answer (score 0):

Change HTML to:

```
<button  ng-click="myFunction($event)">test</button> //onclick works on javascript. For Angularjs, use ng-click.
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.someClickEvent = function(e) {
  // some identification code here
  var element = e.target; // this will give you the reference to the element.
}
```

You should avoid handling DOM in the controller. Use directives for them.

Comment: Note: `e.target` will be a reference to the node *clicked*. `e.currentTarget` will be a reference to the node you attached your event handler to. Sometimes `e.target !== e.currentTarget`, for example when clicking on a child node of `e.currentTarget`. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click)